# Oracle SQL View: Multiple rows to one with help of foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:

**Table A:**

```
pk_id,
value
```

**Table B:**

```
pk_id,
key,
value,
fk_id
```

e.g.
**table a:**

```
1, value
```

e.g. **table b:**

```
1, key1, value1, 1
2, key2, value2, 1
3, key3, value3, 1
```

and so on, it's not possible to define a table with all the keys, because we get that data from another application and it's not always the same and bound to change.

What I need is a view (or if it's possible by other means, I wouldn't mind either) that displays data like this:

```
id, value, key1, key2, key3
1, value, value1, value2, value3
```

so everything connected with one row in table A is displayed in one row. Defining the keys from table B that should be displayed in the view would be possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a [pivotal query](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html). Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I did try the pivot functionality but couldn't figure out how to use it without aggregate function. With the answers below I can write the query I need, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query. This will help you.

```
SELECT a.pk_id,a.value,
MAX(CASE WHEN b.key='key1' THEN b.value ELSE '0' END) AS key1,
MAX(CASE WHEN b.key='key2' THEN b.value ELSE '0' END) AS key2,
MAX(CASE WHEN b.key='key3' THEN b.value ELSE '0' END) AS key3
FROM table_b b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_a a on a.pk_id = b.fk_id
GROUP BY b.fk_id,a.pk_id,a.value
ORDER BY b.fk_id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done using a view, because views have a pre-determined number of columns. You'd have to construct SQL like the following and use a SYS_REFCURSOR to query:

```
select a.pk_id,
       a.value,
       max(decode(b.key, 'key1', b.value)) key1,
       max(decode(b.key, 'key2', b.value)) key2,
       max(decode(b.key, 'key3', b.value)) key3
from   a
left join b on a.pk_id = b.fk_id
group by a.pk_id, a.value
;
```